# Apache2.2 mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2.2

I have a page and would like to use the rewrite module to make the urls more user friendly. I'd like to rewrite these (the user inputs):

```
http://domain.com/folder/page1
http://domain.com/folder/page2
http://domain.com/folder/pagen
```

.. to these:

```
http://domain.com/folder/?id=page1
http://domain.com/folder/?id=page2
http://domain.com/folder/?id=pagen
```

Can you help me write the .htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aw... meanwhile - after I had my lunch - I solved the problem with:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # If the requested url is not an existing file.. 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    # .. neither an existing folder ..
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # .. substitute it with the augmented index.php!
    RewriteRule (.*) index.php?id=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks for the interest! :)